# is there a way to kill a spark job if it running over x minutes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am using a bash to run the same spark(scala) function over multiple data sets. some of these data sets will take extremely long time and I want to skip them so that I can finish as many as possible data sets in limited time. 
is there a way in scala function that I can use to terminate the job if it runs over x minutes?
for you information I am using a bash as:
for filename in dataFolder/*; do  spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --class myclass myclass.jar ${filename}; done

Comment: see [timeout](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Before running the for loop
try something like this

`(sleep 3600 && yarn application -kill myclass)&` to start timeout in background

if myclass is dynamic, use a bash function to get current yarn application id, like `APPID=$(yarn application -list | grep some id | awk 'print {$1}')` or something